# Prove inequality by induction: $\sum _{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} > 2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-1\right)$ for $n \ge 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction

I worked through most of this problem but am getting stuck on the final bit.

Base: $n = 1$: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} > 2(\sqrt{2}-1)\to\sqrt{9}> \sqrt{8}$. through moving stuff around

Hypothesis: true for $n = k$, $\sum _{i=1}^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}>2\sqrt{k+1}-1$

Induction: for $n = k+1$, $\sum _{i=1}^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}>2\left(\sqrt{\left(k+1\right)+1}-1\right) = 2\left(\sqrt{k+1}-1\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

I've tried all kinds of things after this, but can't seem to get it to the right spot. Anyone have insight?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} > \frac{2}{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}$

Comment: Hint: Prove the inequality $ 2 ( \sqrt{k+1} - 1 ) +  1/ \sqrt{k+1}  > 2 ( \sqrt{k+2} - 1 ) $  and you would have completed the induction step. Why is this inequality true?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to prove, I'm just having an issue manipulating it into a form that is logically true

Comment: If so, brush up on inequalities. How can we prove inequalities involving radicals? Perhaps try squaring both sides to reduce the number of radicals. If that doesn't help, is there a way to rearrange before squaring? What about some factorizations to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Where $S(k+1)$ is the sum of $k+1$ terms, you have

$S(k+1)>2(\sqrt{k+1}-1)+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}.$

Now render

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k+1}}>\color{blue}{\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k+2}+\sqrt{k+1}}}$

and multiply the numerator and denominator of the blue expression by the appropriate conjugate. What happens then?